# How to record video using webcam from all browsers C#

Tags: asp.net, video, cross-browser, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I have a requirement of capturing video with audio from users and upload it to the server. I have worked around with Media Stream recording.

I have adopted the code example from following link.

https://simpl.info/mediarecorder/

I am basically converting the video file to base64 string and upload that to the server. However, this functionality does not support by our friendly safari browser.

The idea is to use any webcam regardless of device such as Windows or Mac computers or even Ipads. I am developing the site using .net technologies.

Any help would be much appreciated. Please note that it could be a similar thread to others but not duplicate one.

As discussed in the comment, I am attaching the code sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta name="description" content="Simplest possible examples of HTML, CSS and JavaScript." />
  <meta name="author" content="//samdutton.com">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="simpl.info: simplest possible examples of HTML, CSS and JavaScript">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="/images/icons/icon192.png">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#fff">

  <base target="_blank">

  <title>MediaStream Recording</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://simpl.info/mediarecorder" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <video id="gum" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="recorded" autoplay loop></video>

    <div>
      <button id="record">Start Recording</button>
      <button id="play" disabled>Play</button>
      <button id="download" disabled>Download</button>
    </div>



  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/lib/ga.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample JS File

```
'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */

// This code is adapted from
// https://rawgit.com/Miguelao/demos/master/mediarecorder.html

'use strict';

/* globals MediaRecorder */

// This code is adapted from
// https://rawgit.com/Miguelao/demos/master/mediarecorder.html

var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
var mediaRecorder;
var recordedBlobs;
var sourceBuffer;

var gumVideo = document.querySelector('video#gum');
var recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');

var recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
var playButton = document.querySelector('button#play');
var downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');
recordButton.onclick = toggleRecording;
playButton.onclick = play;
downloadButton.onclick = download;

// window.isSecureContext could be used for Chrome
var isSecureOrigin = location.protocol === 'https:' ||
location.host === 'localhost';
if (!isSecureOrigin) {
  alert('getUserMedia() must be run from a secure origin: HTTPS or localhost.' +
    '\n\nChanging protocol to HTTPS');
  location.protocol = 'HTTPS';
}

// Use old-style gUM to avoid requirement to enable the
// Enable experimental Web Platform features flag in Chrome 49

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

var constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: true
};

navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(stream) {
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream: ', stream);
  window.stream = stream;
  if (window.URL) {
    gumVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  } else {
    gumVideo.src = stream;
  }
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

// navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
// .then(function(stream) {
//   console.log('getUserMedia() got stream: ', stream);
//   window.stream = stream; // make available to browser console
//   if (window.URL) {
//     gumVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
//   } else {
//     gumVideo.src = stream;
//   }
// }).catch(function(error) {
//   console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
// });

function handleSourceOpen(event) {
  console.log('MediaSource opened');
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');
  console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer);
}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}

function handleStop(event) {
  console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
}

function toggleRecording() {
  if (recordButton.textContent === 'Start Recording') {
    startRecording();
  } else {
    stopRecording();
    recordButton.textContent = 'Start Recording';
    playButton.disabled = false;
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  }
}

// The nested try blocks will be simplified when Chrome 47 moves to Stable
function startRecording() {
  var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm', bitsPerSecond: 100000};
  recordedBlobs = [];
  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e0) {
    console.log('Unable to create MediaRecorder with options Object: ', e0);
    try {
      options = {mimeType: 'video/webm,codecs=vp9', bitsPerSecond: 100000};
      mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
    } catch (e1) {
      console.log('Unable to create MediaRecorder with options Object: ', e1);
      try {
        options = 'video/vp8'; // Chrome 47
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
      } catch (e2) {
        alert('MediaRecorder is not supported by this browser.\n\n' +
            'Try Firefox 29 or later, or Chrome 47 or later, with Enable experimental Web Platform features enabled from chrome://flags.');
        console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e2);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  playButton.disabled = true;
  downloadButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(10); // collect 10ms of data
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
  recordedVideo.controls = true;
  var base64data;
  var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  var as =window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
   var reader = new window.FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(superBuffer); 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
                base64data = reader.result;                
                console.log(base64data );
                document.write(base64data);
  }

}

function play() {
  var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
}

function download() {

  var blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
}
```

**UPDATE**

After reading several documents. I finally found a third party plugin to get WebRTC working in Safari and IE which has been provided by Skylink.

Here is the link - https://confluence.temasys.com.sg/display/TWPP

However, this still does not resolve the overall issue of recording the video it shows streaming but does not provide support to save for later use. I really don't want to use Flash as I then have to buy a flash media server. Is there any other way to do this ?

Like, can I host live stream to somewhere and then provide link to watch it later or convert stream to base64string and store that to the database.

Comment: need your effort so that we can help you

Comment: Sure things. Do you want me to attach the code?

Comment: yes , need to see the code what you tried, where you stuck and how do want us to hellp u

Comment: It is absolutely working fine from Chrome and Firefox, however it returns an error from Safari saying the MediaStream doesn't support by the browser.

Comment: @Webruster I have attached the sample code. Full example can be found on the given link in the description. Safari doesn't even open the webcam

Comment: safari in Windows ? or MAC , if its windows , Apple doesnt provide any support for `Safari -windows`

Comment: @Webruster both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127680/discussion-between-ravi-vyas-and-webruster).